# AWS Glue Job: How to provide binaries and make them executable within pythonshell script?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-glue

Problem statement:

S3 Bucket with 7z archives -> Glue Job (Extraction + Aggregation) via pythonshell -> S3 Bucket

I want to solve this via unmanaged instances via AWS Glue.
The 7z files are too big to be used with Lambda (most of the files are >= 2.5 GB + Overhead) and might exceed execution time. 
In general, 7z is not supported natively by any of the "serverless" approaches.
Consequently one has to provide the binaries OR use a native (python) code implementation.

Let's assume there is no stable native implementation. 
I'm curious about how to provide the binaries + libs in general for AWS "serverless" instances?

What I tried so far:

- Just copied the binaries via S3 (with permissions a+x) to `/usr/local/bin` + `/usr/local/lib`.
  Got a permission denied, when calling the binary. Also tried to move it to `/home/$(echo $USER)/bin` + `/home/$(echo $USER)/lib` and added both to the `PATH` env variable.
- Compiled the source of the binary for the Amazon Linux Platform. Set the lib path to a folder with permissions. From the procedure, it's similar to the previous step.
- tried to install the additional binary from the package manager - permission denied

What is the proper way to make the executable binaries with their libs available for unmanaged cluster services like Glue and Co?
I am not talking about Lambdas! For Lambda it's mentioned on an AWS document.

Comment: what are the libraries that you want to use?

Comment: as mentioned in the question, an example would be 7z

Comment: @mchlfchr were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: @Rohit I skipped Glue, because it was too pricy for my use-case and switched over to ECS Fargate, which is working like a charm.